# Azure B2C - Google consent screen shows "Choose an account to continue to b2clogin.com" (not mydomain.com)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've hooked up Google OAuth to B2C, and it works great except that the consent screen shows "b2clogin.com" instead of "mydomain.com" like so:

[image]

Any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't think so. They are obviously using the domain of the Redirect URI instead of any property specified in the Google Cloud console. Underneath the Name property, it even says "The name of your OAuth 2.0 client. This name is only used to identify the client in the console and will not be shown to end users."
This link documents the parameters accepted and I don't see anything here that would help. https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#authenticationuriparameters